# something like database but not a database and sum price

Tags: haskell

How can I sum prices where month = 5 and year = 2010 ? I have date in data Subject and prices in data Sell, they are connected by id. This is my code:

```
-- subject id, date
data Subject = Subject Int CalendarTime deriving (Read, Show)

-- sell id, subject id, price
data Sell = Sell Int Int Double deriving (Read, Show)
```

Comment: How are the stores of Subject and Sell structures?  Is each Subject an element in a list?  A database (sql or otherwise)? Just a list?

Comment: What have you got so far? There is no way to tell from this question what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

Real world uses should probably use a database or at least a mapping (from the containers or unordered-containers packages), but a simple solution can be obtained using simple list comprehension.

Assuming you have simple lists of Subject and Sell:

```
type Subjects = [Subject]
type Sells = [Sell]
```

You could make an O(n*m) implementation (good for play only!):

```
 price :: Sell -> Double
 price (Sell _ _ d) = d

 calTime :: Subject -> CalendarTime
 calTime (Subject _ c) = c

 sIdent :: Subject -> Int  -- Omitted, you should use record syntax anyway
 eIdent :: Sell -> Int  -- Omitted

 sumPred :: (CalendarTime -> Bool) -> Subjects -> Sells -> Double
 sumPred js es = sum [price e | j <- js, e <- es
                     , sIdent j == eIdent e
                     , pred (calTime j)]
```

But as I said, that's foolish.  Using a DB with Subjects keyed by CalendarTime and Sell's keyed by identity will give you a more practical solution.

Comment: eh... to unspecific for me to help you understand.